# Scrollable dialog in Material-UI beta for React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design

I'm using the great Material-ui components for building my react app and have used the  component on several pages. My issue is that the component doesn't seem to support scrollable content.

Is there any easy way to make a workaround and make the content of the component scrollable if it exceeds the total height?

Comment: `overflow: scroll`, maybe ?

Comment: Thanks! This works. However, it only works when I hard code a height for my scrollable content. Can I make this dynamic so it looks good across different screen sizes?